# Проблема в типе array при создании итератора вручную и вызова его методов

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Посмотрите мой код с типом array. Странная ошибка компиляции когда тип объявлен как **auto** все хорошо, а при создании типа итератора вручную не работают методы **rbegin()** и **rend()**. возможно ли что это ошибка компилятора mvs 2010?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::array<int, 5> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (auto ait = a.rbegin(); ait != a.rend(); ++ait) // здесь все хорошо 
        std::cout << *ait << std::endl;                 // ошибки нет

    std::array<int, 5>::iterator it;

    for (it = a.rbegin(); it != a.rend(); ++it) // здесь ошибка компиляции
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

компилятор выдает ошибки: C2679 и C2678

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**rbegin** и **rend** возвращают [reverse_iterator/const_reverse_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/rbegin).

```
std::array<int, 5>::reverse_iterator it;
```

или

```
std::array<int, 5>::const_reverse_iterator it;
```